# the Back Button Linking shows an Error with the @IBAction text

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

-> Only instance methods can be declared @IBAction,
I need the button to take go to the previous terminal. What is wrong with it?

@IBAction func GoBack(_ sender: Any) {
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

Comment: Are you linking a button, a touchGesture, what is being linked?

Comment: Yeah I tried linking a back button(action)

Comment: Please clarify your question

Comment: I need to create a back button that leads me to the main story board

Comment: i tried to use dismiss to cancel the view function but it isnt working, how do i get this right?